Host a directory as a local server
I am making a code editor using Godot 4.4-dev7.
I want to host the home project directory as a local server (like 127.0.0.1:8000) to allow the user to see their code result (like HTML pages).
Is there any way to do that using one of godot built-in classes?
Godot has many classes for networking and connections but I can't find the right one to use it for that purpose.
